# Python : name 'set_password' is not defined

Tags: python, django, encryption, hash

Im trying to register users hashing their passwords before add to database as follows

**settings.py**

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
)
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class Users(AbstractBaseUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password =  models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**Views.py**

```
name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
date_joined = date.today()

if Users.objects.filter(email=email).exists() and Users.objects.filter(name=name).exists() :
    messages.info(request, 'User already exists')
else:
    Users.objects.create(name=name, email=email, password=set_password(password), date_joined=date_joined)
```

but when i actually trying to create the user i get `Python : name 'set_password' is not defined`
What is wrong? do i need to import something at `Views.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [`set_password()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.set_password) on a user instance, not when creating a user.

Try this:

```
user = Users.objects.create(first_name=name, email=email, date_joined=date_joined)
user.set_password(password)
user.save()
```

I can see you are extending the user model. I'd have a look at some articles for ways to do this, I recommend this [article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much! At the login state do i repeat the same process?

Comment: Its a different process, you can just use the password from the form. Have a look at the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login

Comment: i think ```authenticate() ```checks for the unhashed password. This is not working in my case

Comment: `authenticate()` does not check for the unhashed password. The password is never stored in the DB as unhashed since you have set: `'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher'`. It will hash the password from the form and check if the hashed form password matches the hashed password in the DB. This way, the password in the DB is never "unhashed".

Comment: I just wanted to highlight here is, Django doesn’t support `name` & if you try to pass it to constructor like `User(name='Rishikesh')` this then you will observe `TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'` exception. As it supports `first_name`, `last_name`, `username` etc.